# Funcion que obtenga la fecha inicio y fecha fin

Tags: mysql, sql

Como puedo hacer que una funcion me permita obtener la fecha inicio y fecha fin es decir de los campos que estan la tabla ctemporada estoy trabajando en mysql

```
CREATE TABLE ctemporada (
  Id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  Nombre varchar(30) ,
  FechaInicio DATE,
  FechaFin DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
) engine=innodb;
```

esto es lo que llevo

```
create definer=`root`@`localhost` function `TEST1` (inNombre varchar(100)) returns date
 begin
 declare fecha DATE; 
 return @fecha;
 end
```

Comment: si una funcion debe ser solo una funcion pero con el uso de parametros que permita realizar obtener dichos valores

Comment: si ya lo puse lo que llevo al momento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que dado lo que buscas una [función](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-function-udf.html) no es la mejor opción

- Cuando declares la función tendrías que indicar lo que dicha función espera retornar y si por ejemplo tu plan es devolver todos los registros de las columnas de fecha y lo declaras como `VARCHAR` esa estructura no empataría con el dato que la función pretende devolver
- Si revisamos la naturaleza de las funciones es:

  - Recibe parámetros (no siempre)
  - Usa los parámetros para procesarlos mediante una lógica interna (o hace algo internamente)
  - Retorna un valor calculado
  - Muestra el resultado de ese procesamiento cuando la invocas
- Pudieras en estos casos usar un procedimiento almacenado dentro del cual declares la sentencia deseada
- Dicho procedimiento también puede o no esperar parámetros con los cuales trabajar para filtrar tus consultas
- Cada que lo invoques te devolverá la estructura o tabla de valores esperados de tu tabla

Lo anterior que te menciono por qué cuando invocamos a una función del modo:

```
SELECT nombreFuncion(columna) FROM tabla;
```

Esperaríamos que `nombreFuncion()` procese y haga algo con los valores de `columna` pero en realidad no pasará pues la única intención es retornar los valores que dicha columna tiene como un `SELECT` genérico.

Dado lo anterior, yo haría esto:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE seleccionaFechas()
BEGIN
    SELECT fechaInicio, fechaFin FROM ctemporada;
END ;
//
```

Y entonces cada que necesites los datos simplemente llamas al procedimiento almacenado:

```
CALL seleccionaFechas;
```

**Lecturas recomendadas**

- [enlace 1](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,406891)
- [enlace 2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html)